# Error: Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values

Tags: drop-down-menu, duplicates

I'm trying to create a dropdown in Google Forms from my Google Contact List but Get this Error: Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values.  How can I resolve this in Google Script?

```
`function GetContactsAndMakeThemDropdown(){
  // Copy your form ID from the browser address bar when you open the form in edit mode
 var form = FormApp.openById('1FZlDC4STjgoFPlzUUSZ9LAIJd6dobRJhm43wag81KYA'); 
var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
     var arr=[]
  //i<contacts.length; i++
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
   for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
//Access my contacts and get all contact name that not blank (name.length>0)
    var name = contacts[i].getFullName();
     if(name.length>0 ){
       arr.push(name); }
    
   }
   
   // Add the contact name to the first dropdown list found in my form
     
     formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(arr.sort()); `
  }
```

I think here is where the issue is.

`formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(arr.sort());`